# What is the this[''] accessor that shows up in Drools

Tags: java, this, drools

Just looking for a way to pass parameters into a getter in **Drools**...

I have noticed in Eclipse Ganymede that intellisense is helpful in determining the getters that can be used to select an entity in a Drools WHERE clause.  Just type a letter and hit ctrl+Space to see the list.  I have another project in **Drools.NET** that relies on C# Properties instead of get methods.  **C#.NET** lets you define a default property as `public String this[String key]` so you can refer to a list without any property as `myInstance["myKeyString"]` and I have used this in **Drools.NET**.  I was hoping that the `this['']` option that appears in **Java Drools** between the curlies of a WHERE clause entity selector like `myInstance : myClass { ... }` refers to something similar.

Is this true, and if so, how do I use it?

Answer (score 0):

No isn't an equivalent of that style of properties in drools java - all facts must be strongly defined up front before compiling.

There may be a way to use a field which is a Map though, and access things via keys.